# Can can I identify my deposits to a wallet on a BTC (or LTC) blockchain (using the blockcypher api)

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, blockcypher

I'm trying to reconcile my deposits to a wallet (happens to be LTC) on an exchange account with the data on the blockchain.  I was using the logic:

```
if tx_input_n is -1 then
    transaction is a deposit
else
    transaction isn't a deposit
```

Which I now know isn't correct.  In this this wallet for example: http://explorer.litecoin.net/address/37GjCWCfLuxMaeKZz5yepLSS1Jpd3MfKmG, there are 20 blockchain deposits using the logic I've described.  5 of them however are (correctly) not represented in my exchange account because they aren't deposits:

```
2017-07-22T10:56:32Z b9ed3bbf129307b0a36fbb723e3a11d40959b4e109c01983a8ee2f0589cf52e5 0.02873313LTC 
2017-07-28T14:40:44Z 2440d14ba777ac204b332f2e2043f415cb0d10670b4ca4f4b38284d3c8bbf9ef 4.61365117LTC 
2017-07-28T14:51:26Z baf74fe93ade6f9dc8a15a2e5b6ac5923bb9cd40877a493933ffc21384538f24 18.03466901LTC
2017-07-28T22:46:47Z c55c669edf7bcd2c6a334269f13d93a00e1d6785304af4e389376ccfc3503261 5.89897287LTC 
2017-07-31T14:42:27Z 6743cb062ab904a050adc90933f0cc02e4188073a7ff3f0e552576431230dc84 10.79192514LTC
```

What are these 5 transactions?  Or more specifically: **how do I identify my deposits in the blockchain so that I can reconcile them with my exchange account?**

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but why not. 
1st, the example address is MDUsWPcdJ2onP9bU5xxzdygqL1R51aAvva. It has 31 total transactions: 
https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=6&data=MDUsWPcdJ2onP9bU5xxzdygqL1R51aAvva

The first transaction is this one:
https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=6&data=b9ed3bbf129307b0a36fbb723e3a11d40959b4e109c01983a8ee2f0589cf52e5+

45 LTC was taken from the given address and bundled with 16 other inputs. 48 LTC was snet to LSd8c9iv8JuyFbi3ejEAdpqPcdRyhsiF4H and the remaining .02873313 LTC was returned to the MDU address.

What you are likely seeing here is change. To send that 48 from MDU it had to bundle together enough to cover the 48 along with the ~0.68 fee. The remainder was returned to MDU as change.

In your second example, 
https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=6&data=2440d14ba777ac204b332f2e2043f415cb0d10670b4ca4f4b38284d3c8bbf9ef+

This transaction took multiple inputs from the MDU address along with a few others to cover what looks like the Lgam transaction of 10.7 LTC. This seems like a sloppy way of handling the inputs as the change resulted in more than one of the MDU inputs. Seems like juggling the inputs for no reason only to have it come back to the same address. Waste of gas in my opinion. The 3.09299- MDU input could have been dropped completely and this transaction would have still been fine.

I could go through the remainder but at this point i'd prefer more information.

1. Which exchange are you using?
2. What does the exchange say are you deposits/withdrawals (line by line)?
3. What is your actual exchange "deposit" address?

I'm not sure you want to tell me exactly what your wallet is, if it is indeed this one. Ultimately exchanges in most cases don't let you "own" your wallet. You don't have the private key to it, it's shared among many other accounts. You "own" the number next to "LTC" and they juggle everything else as they see fit.